# What are the algorithms for block finding in graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I want to know about the algorithms for finding block in graph. Which one works good for directed graph and which one for undirected? Also the performance, complexity of those algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is too broad. Please consider reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and editing it, so people feel more inclined to help

Comment: What kind of blocks? Strongly connected components?